# Linker command failed with exit code 1 when using CATransition

Tags: ios, linker, quartz-core

I want to make my view's transition to slide from right to left instead of the usual left to right. So I found this code :

```
- (void) imgSlideInFromLeft : (UIView *) view
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.4;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}
```

Then I added QuartzCore's framework and imported `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, but I'm getting these errors now :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SearchResultsController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SearchResultsController.o
  "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
      -[SearchResultsController imgSlideInFromLeft:] in SearchResultsController.o
  "_kCATransitionFromLeft", referenced from:
      -[SearchResultsController imgSlideInFromLeft:] in SearchResultsController.o
  "_kCATransitionPush", referenced from:
      -[SearchResultsController imgSlideInFromLeft:] in SearchResultsController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you should make sure that QuartzCore framework is linked to your project

Comment: try doing clean build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotten to add the `QuartzCore.framework` to your app?